# SQL - How to select a column alias from another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table in SQL with data and another table that holds the alias for that column. It is used for translation purposes.

I was wondering how can I do a select on those columns but retrieve the alias from another table?

This is the table that holds the real column names:

```
ID      PageID  ColName         Order   Type    Width   IsDeleted
1   7   CustType    2   NULL    NULL    0
2   7   Description 3   NULL    NULL    0
3   7   ApplyVAT    4   NULL    NULL    0
4   7   ProduceInvoices 5   NULL    NULL    0
5   7   PurchaseSale    6   NULL    NULL    0
6   7   TermsDays   7   NULL    NULL    0
7   7   DateTimeLastUpdated 8   NULL    NULL    0
```

This is the table that holds the alias (text):

```
ID      ColID   UserID  Text            Order   Enabled?
50  22  1   id          1       1
51  1   1   CustTypes   2   1
52  2   1   Description 3   1
53  3   1   ApplyVAT    NULL    0
54  4   1   ProduceInvoices NULL    0
55  5   1   PurchaseSale    NULL    0
56  6   1   TermsDays   NULL    0
57  7   1   DateTimeLastUpdated NULL    0
```

Comment: Sorry about the layout of the table, I can never get them to come out looking right on here.

Comment: Do you build up all your queries dynamically, from the 'Table which holds the real column names'? Also, how do you support more than one translation for the same columns in the alias table? (e.g. By `UserId`?)

Comment: At the moment because of the stage that I'm at, I am taking the list from the translated table (by User) if something has been added for that page and user. I need to be able to do a select on the database table using the columns from the static table and display the columns that the user has translated. The select statement is dynamically created at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to use dynamic sql to do this, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT TOP 1 @Sql = 'SELECT dt.ID as ' + at.IDAlias + ', dt.Town as ' + at.TownAlias 
                  + ' FROM DataTable dt'
FROM AliasTable at
WHERE at.LanguageID = 2;
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Given the example of Data Table

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable
(
   ID INT,
   Town NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

And a table holding language - dependent aliases for the columns in the above:

```
CREATE TABLE AliasTable
(
   LanguageId INT,
   IDAlias NVARCHAR(100),
   TownAlias NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dbe9/4)

One of the (many) caveats with dynamic Sql is you will need to ensure that the alias data is validated against Sql Injectin attacks.

Comment: I have tried this and for some reason I get Invalid column name 'CustType'. returned as an error although the column does exist. I also took the generated sql columns and did a select with those and it worked. Is there any reason why it might not work with dynamic SQL?

Comment: The problem is that you are getting tangled up with pre-projected and post-projected column names. Once you have applied the CTE to project names, you need to then use the post-projected column names in the final select (By then, the column name is `CustTypes` because of the mapping) [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3338/28)

Comment: Ah OK, got it, I will remember for future CTE's. Thanks.