# Postgres / SQL row headers from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database with two tables that I want to merge into one.

The first table looks like (for example):

```
Datetime  | Obj236 | Obj326 | Obj337
timestamp | value  | value  | value
timestamp | value  | value  | value
timestamp | value  | value  | value
```

The second is:

```
ID   | Type
236  | Headername1
326  | Headername2
337  | Headername3
```

Is there a query that returns the first table but with the proper header name:

```
Datetime | Headername1 | Headername2 | Headername3
timestamp| value       | value       | value
timestamp| value       | value       | value
timestamp| value       | value       | value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless you build a dynamic query.

First you need to obtain the name used as alias, and then build the query that assign this alias to the corresponding columns.

There are some samples in SO:

- [How can I dynamically alias columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59062/how-can-i-dynamically-alias-columns)
- [SQL - How to select a column alias from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297252/sql-how-to-select-a-column-alias-from-another-table)
- [SQL Server: How to set column alias from another table during select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361596/sql-server-how-to-set-column-alias-from-another-table-during-select)

Answer (score -1):

Do this.

```
  SELECT Datetime,
         Obj236 as Headername1,
         Obj326 as Headername2,
         Obj337 as Headername3
  FROM    dbname;
```